# can google script objects be cached?

Tags: google-apps-script

Im learning google script and i found that using the cache can make code run much faster. unfortunately, in a code im working on, there is an "onEdit" function that needs to fetch all sheets everytime it runs. I tried cache-ing the sheets calling getSheets, stringifying the result and then adding that to the cache. but apparently that method doesn't work. when calling the value of the key in the cache i stored the sheets, it only returns a list of white spaces.
Is it that this kind of objects cannot be cached? or is there some other way to solving this problem?

thank you very much!

Comment: Don't think it can be cached. In any case, rework your script flow- why would you need to get all sheets on every edit?

Comment: Apps Script Classes can not be cached.  They can be put into a global variable so that different functions don't need to make additional service calls.  If you have concurrent users of the same script, globals would get overwritten if one user triggers the same code before the first instance of the code has finished.  In that case you'd want to use LockService.

Comment: Could they be stringified before caching and then parsed after removing from cache.  Even if that worked it would probably take so long such as to nullify the reason for doing it in the first place.

Comment: Yes you can use [Cache](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache), but with [onEdit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) everything changes, as you always gather new data.